# WebSockets disconnecting with Opera VPN

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, websocket, opera

I have a websocket/nodejs based chat, which is working well with Chrome/Firefox/Edge/Opera (embedded vpn disabled).

However, when I turn on the embedded VPN in Opera, I get randomly disconnected. Usually it happens after something like 10 seconds, irrespective of me sending message or not. If I send messages, they all go through well until the disconnection after 10 seconds or so. The disconnect happens even without any message.

Not sure if it can be related, but I use nodejs behind a Apache Proxy configured as follows (HTTP behind 8081, WSS behind 8080, all encapsulated in 443):

```
<VirtualHost MY_IP:443>
     ServerName www.mydomain.com

     SSLProxyEngine On

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

     SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
     Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
     RewriteRule /(.*)           wss://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

     ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost localhost:8081>
     DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

I am stuck as I don't get any error message on client or server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found some requests are missing several header, e.g. `Connection: Upgrade` and `Upgrade: websocket`. It feels like either WebSocket client on Opera browser is faulty by not sending those 2 headers, or Opera's proxy server probably **downgraded the client's secure Websocket request**, decrypt and drop some headers, because other Websocket handshake headers like `Sec-WebSocket-*` are left intact.

I don't know exactly in your case, perhaps you should see your logs and look at the headers received on the server. When I look at the load balancer's log that has this issue, somehow most of the user agents logged are opera on mobile device, there are in desktop opera with vpn where it successfully connected, but there are times when it failed.